# Creating public methods in class and not in interface

Tags: unit-testing, oop, language-agnostic, access-modifiers

I've come across an issue whether it is a good idea to create public methods/properties inside a class

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
```

but not in the interface

```
public interface IMyClass
```

mainly for the purpose of unit testing implemented methods from `IMyClass` inside  `MyClass`. I want to have access from my unit tests to implementation details inside class `MyClass` to check if some fields meet the expectations. Additionaly, I don't want to expose these details through my interface.

On the other hand, I have a feeling that everything public inside `MyClass` should be exposed in the interface `IMyClass`, since this is the case of access modifiers:
 `public` to expose information, `private` to hide details.

So, my the question is: Is it good to create public methods/properties inside a class `MyClass`, but not in the interface `IMyClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test is supposed to be a client of your code, using your code through its interface.

Writing a test that knows how your code works couples your test to your code, which makes a brittle test - every change to the code will break the test.

Instead, try to exercise your code using only the API. Since it sounds like your class has state in it, your test code will need to query that state in another API call.

If your API doesn't have a querying mechanism, perhaps the test is trying to tell you that such a feature is missing from your code.